# Send Laravel notification without entity

Tags: laravel

I understand that with Laravel notifications I can use

```
Notification::send(User::first(), new TodoCompleted($task));
```

But what if I want to send a notification, to Slack in my case, with some custom details stored in an array (`$task` in the example above) but without having to pass a entity/model (`User::first()` in the example above). Is that possible?

Comment: What would you be passing instead? Also, what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I'd like to pass an array with data (`$tasks` in the example) only. Using 5.8.17 (latest version atm).

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/notifications#on-demand-notifications

Comment: Thanks. Classic case of RTFM on my part... But a last question on using on demand notifications. In the docs they put the function routNotificationForSlack that returns the webhook url in the model. But if I use on demand notifications I don’t use a model. So how does it know the webhook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To send a notification without using model you will want to use [on demand notifications](http://laravel.com/docs/master/notifications#on-demand-notifications):

```
Notification::route('slack', 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/...')
        ->notify(new TodoCompleted($task));
```

Just replace `https://hooks.slack.com/services/...` with the url that you would usually return from the `routNotificationForSlack` method.

Comment: Thanks. I've actually put the webhook in the env file, and then link to that env webhook from the services config file.